# Issue with MERGE statement - error in semicolon (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have done everything i know about MERGE in this fiddle but am not getting output.Hope someone will come up with a solution for this.

I have done a simple MERGE statement to insert, update and delete the values of target table using source table  at the same time  and everything is fine but am getting error message saying

[image: Error - A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)]

I have put semi-colon but the error keeps popping up.I am studying MERGE statements and how to use them using two table using SQLFiddle and someone please show me the correct approach to place the semi-colon.

Here's the fiddle - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf3dd/20)

and here's the code of MERGE

```
MERGE Students AS T 

USING Teachers AS S
ON S.LastName = T. LastName and
S.FirstName = T.FirstName

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T.Address = S.Address,
         T.Age = S.Age 

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (LastName, 
      FirstName, 
      Address, 
      Age) 
      VALUES (S.LastName, 
      S.FirstName, 
      S.Address, 
      S.Age)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
DELETE;

OUTPUT $action, Inserted.LastName, Inserted.FirstName, Deleted.LastName, Deleted.FirstName INTO @T;

Select * from @T;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf3dd/47/0)**, `@T` definition was wrong, I also removed semicolon after `DELETE` and changed the query terminator on SQL Fiddle to `GO` instead of semicolon.

Comment: Thank you..I should have added that action column but didn't think like that..now i got it..Thanks..but i have got one doubt though, in this SQl Fiddle, you have used semi-colon to terminate each line then why change it to GO? Are we using it?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help. Actually Fiddle that I posted works with any 'query terminator' other than semicolon. Unfortunately I can't tell why choosing this option seems to interfere with query parsing. In this Fiddle we weren't actually using `GO` batch delimiter. 'Query terminator' just needed to be changed to something other than `;` to avoid parsing error.